# What is CHAR(7) in Teradata SQL in date format?

Tags: sql, date, teradata

I am trying to get the idea of `char(7)` in the following SQL in Teradata:

```
SELECT current_date (FORMAT'YYYY-MM') (char(7));
```

as far as it forces the display of the correct format, exactly as specified. 
When I try without `char(7)` at the end, the format is not as specified, e.g.:

```
SELECT current_date (FORMAT 'YYYY-MM');
```

returns the day as well, ignoring the format command:

[image]

As a subquestion - is this the correct way to display the month and the year from a date column? (with `char(7)`)

Comment: The "correct" way to display month and year depends on your rule, `'2020JAN'`, `'202001'` as strings or `202001` as integer, etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would suggest using `TO_CHAR` here:

```
SELECT TO_CHAR(CURRENT_DATE, 'YYYY-MM');
```

This takes the guesswork out of your problem, as the contract of `TO_CHAR` is to return a string representation of the input datetime using the format mask you specify.  You do not need to worry about requesting a certain string width.

Comment: So, `char(7)` is actually forcing the teradata to represent the date with a lenght of 7 chars, thus it does its best to follow the format? With other words, `char(7)` is a dirty hack for people, who cannot format dates?

Comment: Probably not (what I assumed in the previous comment), as far as `CURRENT_DATE(FORMAT'YYYY')(char(20))` returns the year, following the format.

Comment: @Vityata: The FORMAT is applied when a date is casted to a string (it was mainly used for creating reports in BTEQ which automatically cast everything to strings). When you run the 2nd Select outside of BTEQ Teradata is returning the original datatype DATE and SQL Assistant formats it locally ignoring the FORMAT. The `CHAR(7)` forces a type cast from date to string done by the DBMS applying the `YYYY-MM` format.

Comment: @dnoeth - I see, I was thinking that the `CHAR(N)` is some kind of enforcement indeed. But I ran the 2nd SELECT inside BTEQ and it still ignores the format() rule.

Comment: BTEQ works as expected: `SELECT current_date (FORMAT 'YYYY-MM');

 *** Query completed. One row found. One column returned.
 *** Total elapsed time was 1 second.

   Date
-------
2020-01` The `(CHAR(7))` is the legacy syntax for `CAST(... AS CHAR(7))`

Comment: @dnoeth - if you combine your comments into an answer, I will accept it.

Comment: @Vityata: Simply accept Tim's answer, it's correct :-)

Comment: @dnoeth - in general it is, but it did not answer the `CHAR(7)` part of the question. Anyway, I am new to the `teradata` tag.